# I want to filter by a date range using a custom date component for Ag-Grid ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I want to filter by a date range instead of a single date using the ReactJS ag grid.

[Here is my code sample in plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jg6or0UWho6yxkJ7)

```
  componentDidMount() {
this.picker = flatpickr(this.refs.flatpickr, {
  onChange: this.onDateChanged.bind(this),
  dateFormat: 'd/m/Y',
  mode:'range',
  wrap: true,
});
```

So I have added ***mode:'range'*** to use a date range for the flatpickr date component that ag-grid uses in their [examples](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-date-component/)

I want to be able to filter the rows in the plnkr example by using the date range. However, I can only pass in one of the dates (the *from* date) to the comparator function in the columnDef.  If I try to pass in an array of dates, I receive an error since ag-grid is only expecting a single date object and not an array of date objects.

```
        {
      field: 'date',
      minWidth: 190,
      filter: 'agDateColumnFilter',
      filterParams: {
        comparator: function(filterLocalDateAtMidnight, cellValue) {
          var dateAsString = cellValue;
          var dateParts = dateAsString.split('/');
          var cellDate = new Date(
            Number(dateParts[2]),
            Number(dateParts[1]) - 1,
            Number(dateParts[0])
          );
          if (filterLocalDateAtMidnight.getTime() === cellDate.getTime()) {
            return 0;
          }
          if (cellDate < filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (cellDate > filterLocalDateAtMidnight) {
            return 1;
          }
        },
      },
    },
```

I suspect I need to overwrite one of the api methods to take in an array of date objects instead of a single date in the column definitions but I cannot seem to do this correctly.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?